# cut-out-and-keep -- meaning?

Tags: meaning

> To appreciate the effects of the applied CSS, it is worth copying this template verbatim at
>   this stage, as that’ll help you understand the examples discussed. Note that the list of links will tie together further templates in this section, giving you a **cut-out-and-keep** mini-site for reference.

What exactly do yo think that adjective means?

Comment: A link to the original would help, but without more context, I would guess that this is quite similar to copy-and-paste, and it sounds like an ad hoc word for the mentioned mini-site that you can copy part of it out, paste or save it somewhere, so that you can keep it as your reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the mini-site is one that you can cut out and then keep. As opposed to looking it up all the time, you could simply pin this up on the wall by your computer so you always have the template handy.

I would assume this is a template that comes on paper, or at least something that is printed.

Answer (score 2):

It's a rather dated usage, [more popular a century ago than today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cut%20out%20and%20keep&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccut%20out%20and%20keep%3B%2Cc0). The reference is to cutting out (perhaps only *part* of) a page from a *magazine/newspaper* (daily/weekly/monthly publications which would normally be thrown away after being read).

Obviously nothing *physical* needs to be kept in OP's context - it's just a figurative extension. The idea is that you'll put the list into a section within your browser's [***bookmarks/favorites***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmark_(World_Wide_Web)).